# SMB share, from windows, creates files are owned by administrator and permissions and for Everyone. How to force this to be user who created file?

Tags: active-directory, file-permissions, user-permissions, smbclient

So I have a smb share setup using unisphere. I can login to my windows machine on the domain and my ad account. I can access the share but when creating a file on the share it shows under security that Everyone has full permissions. Nothing about my user account having permissions.

Selecting advanced shows the owner as administrators.

Is there something wrong with my configuration or what would be the reasons my account wouldn't show up under security and everyone would instead? I can edit permissions and add my user if I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the Creator Owner identity is for. If that is in the folder ACL for subfolders and files, the account that created the file and be assigned the permissions granted to the Creator Owner identity.

Comment: I guess I am confused by this answer. After mounting the smb share from my windows machine as user01...any files or folders I created have an Owner: Administrator and group permissions show everyone has full access.  Should it show my user as the permission holder? Under advanced it also shows inherited from as being the smb share/nas server